# How can you use a `for` loop to change the content of a list?

Tags: python, list

For example:

```py
my_list = [x for x in range(10)]
for i in my_list:
    i += 1
print(my_list)
```

This code will print a list containing numbers between 0 - 9. But I want if I change `i`, the actual value in `my_list` will change too. So for the example, I want it to print between 1 - 10.

I can do:

```
my_list = [x for x in range(10)]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] += 1
print(my_list)
```

but I heard that this kind of `for` loop when you use `len()` is bad. So is there any other way?

---

I know that `i` is not a reference, but I want to make it like one.

Comment: A `for` loop over `range(len(...))` isn't _bad_ per se, but it is a code smell. It means there is _probably_ a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You seem to be confused. Changing individual elements of a list is fine; the problem you seem to be alluding to is related to modifying _the list itself_ (typically, deleting some items) while you are looping over it.

Comment: If you want to generate the final list directly you can use the list comprehension. But If you have an existing list your must keep and update ... using the for i in range(len(my_list)): is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one list comprehension instead of using two loops:

```
my_list = [x+1 for x in range(10)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [x + 1 for x in range(10)]

# or:

my_list = [x for x in range(10)]
my_list = [x + 1 for x in my_list]
```

In your first loop, `i` is just a name, it's not a reference to the list in any way.

Comment: Can I make it so that `i` is a reference?

Comment: No, that is not how Python works. Integers are immutable in Python (for good reason!), so you will need to either modify the list itself or construct a new one.